# Retrieved DateTime displaying incorrectly in classic ASP

Tags: sql-server, datetime, asp-classic

I'm using classic ASP to retrieve and display data from MSSQL. One of the retrieved data items is refusing to display correctly, and I'm at a loss as to what is going on. It's coded as "datetime" in MSSQL, and when I try to display it I either get a blank, or an incorrect date, 30/12/1899.

There is definitely data in the database to be retrieved, but I don't know if the problem lies with its retrieval, or the method of output.

The data item in question is called "DUpdated".

The query is:

```
SELECT DUID, DCountry, DName, DUpdated FROM dbo.Destinations WHERE DUID = '{2BC43BE4-75FD-447B-99B1-1AE414978B96}'
```

This query in MSSQL returns: (I would have posted an image here, but as this is my first post, I don't have the props, apparently). You'll just have to take my word for it.

```
DUID:
2BC43BE4-75FD-447B-99B1-1AE414978B96

DCountry:
South Africa

DName:
131 Herbert Baker

DUpdated:
2012-12-12 14:52:58.207
```

The code to display the data is as follows (it's to be rendered as XML):

```
<hotel>
    <id><%=(hotels.Fields.Item("DUID").Value)%></id>
    <name><![CDATA[<%=(hotels.Fields.Item("DName").Value)%>]]></name>
    <country><![CDATA[<%=(hotels.Fields.Item("DCountry").Value)%>]]></country>
    <lastupdated><%=(FormatDateTime(hotels.Fields.Item("DUpdated").Value,2))%></lastupdated>
</hotel>
```

The output is:

```
<hotel>
    <id>{2BC43BE4-75FD-447B-99B1-1AE414978B96}</id>
    <name><![CDATA[131 Herbert Baker]]></name>
    <country><![CDATA[South Africa]]></country>
    <lastupdated>30/12/1899</lastupdated>
</hotel>
```

What is happening that the value of DUpdated in the database is being displayed as this incorrect date?

Comment: What happens if you do `<%= hotels.Fields.Item("DUPdated") %>` without the call to `FormatDateTime`?

Comment: Hi Dai, nothing is output at all.

Comment: Try `For Each col In hotels.Fields.Item \n Response.Write( col )` and let us know what it says.

Comment: OK, Dai, we're looking at some success here! I get 12/12/2012, which is right. Thank you so much! What's the explanation?

Comment: I think you've got the wrong field name. Try debugging your code - you can use VS to attach to w3wp.exe to step-through your code.

Comment: 30/12/1899 is the default value for a MSSQL date field, which suggests that something isn't writing to that field